# xslt issue - selecting until preceding-sibling changes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I know its been asked before but I'm struggling to get the xpath correct for my scenario:
I want to get the the correct users for a given customer:

```
<root>

<div>
<span>customer1</span>
</div>
<div><img></img></div>
<div>userForCustomer1</div>
<div>anotherUserForCustomer1</div>

<div>
<span>customer2</span>
<div><img></img></div>
</div>
<div>userForCustomer2</div>
<div>anotherForCustomer2</div>

<div>
<span>customer3</span>
<div><img></img></div>
</div>
<div>userForCustomer3</div>
<div>anotherForCustomer3</div>

</root>
```

using the following xpath, I am getting the next set of users:

```
//div[span='customer2']/following-sibling::div[preceding-sibling::div/span = 'customer2']
```

gives us

```
<div>userForCustomer2</div>

<div>anotherForCustomer2</div>

<div>
<span>customer3</span>
<div>
<img/>
</div>
</div>

<div>userForCustomer3</div>

<div>anotherForCustomer3</div>
```

and if I try to stop it going to far with:

```
//div[span='customer2']/following-sibling::div[preceding-sibling::div[1]/span = 'customer2']
```

gives us

```
<div>userForCustomer2</div>
```

it just returns the 1 user, not both users for customer2

what I am after is:

```
<div>userForCustomer2</div>
<div>anotherForCustomer2</div>
```

I'm sure its an easy answer.

Thanks in advance

========================

Update:

```
//div[span='customer2']/following-sibling::div[preceding-sibling::div[span][1]/span= 'customer2']
```

Gets us very close with this result:

```
<result>
<div>userForCustomer2</div>

<div>anotherForCustomer2</div>

<div>
<span>customer3</span>
<div>
<img/>
</div>
</div>

</result>
```

but I guess I need to now trim the divs I dont want such as the one with the img and with customer3 in

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is almost correct, you just need to look at

```
preceding-sibling::div[span][1]
```

(the nearest preceding div-with-a-span) instead of

```
preceding-sibling::div[1]
```

(the nearest preceding `div`, whether it has a `span` child or not).

But personally I would approach this in XSLT with a *key* that links each div-without-a-span to its customer name:

```
<xsl:key name="userByCustomer" match="div[not(span)]"
         use="preceding-sibling::div[span][1]/span" />
```

Now given a particular customer name you can extract all the relevant users with a single function call

```
<xsl:copy-of select="key('userByCustomer', 'customer2')" />
```

Comment: //div[span='customer2']/following-sibling::div[preceding-sibling::div[span][1] /span= 'customer2'] gets us very close<result>
<div>userForCustomer2</div>

<div>anotherForCustomer2</div>

<div>
<span>customer3</span>
<div>
<img/>
</div>
</div>

</result>

Comment: this answer has actually answered the "core" problem I had albeit it doesnt solve this "dumbed down" problem directly

Comment: @user3545403 you could restrict to `div` elements that don't contain any other elements by using `//div[span='customer2']/following-sibling::div[not(*)][preceding-sibling::div[span][1]/span= 'customer2']`.  Or for the key approach, have the key match `div[not(*)]` instead of `div[not(span)]`.

Comment: @user3545403 by the way, your XML is a bit inconsistent - the `img` for customer1 is outside the `<div><span>customer1</span></div>` but the other `img` elements are inside the div, as a sibling of the `span`.